# how to retrieve rows where an attribute == self.id and send email to self.email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, rows

seems it must be simple, but I've been messing around two days with this and can't get it to work.
thanks for any help in advance.

I have 1 table with  self.id , self.number and self.email among others not related.

(first set)some rows have self.id and self.number 
(second set)other rows have self.id and self.email

i want to update a row from the first set and then find all rows from second set in which self.id is equal to self.number, to send them an email.

the last Ive been trying is through scopes like this:

```
 scope :send_alert, (lambda do |self_number| 
   { :conditions => ['self_number = ?', self_id] }
 end)

 scope :send_alert2, (lambda do |self_id| 
   { :conditions => ['self_id = ?', self_number] }
 end)
```

I am not getting errors, everything goes through but nothing happens.
I am using delayed_job and i see that I'm sending the row just updated but not the ones I'm trying to get.

Comment: The scopes look messed up to me.  Try calling the scope in the console to make sure you are getting the result you expect.  I'm pretty sure you are not using the self_number in the way you expect, they need to be reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional callbacks to accomplish this like so

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  # checks if the model has the attribute 'number' and calls send_emails func
  after_update :send_emails, if: :number

  # iterate through where the id matches the given number and call your alert fucntion
  def send_emails
    MyModel.find_by_id(:number).map {|m| m.send_email(m.email)} 
  end

end
```

Comment: in the after_update ,..that you suggest, i don't have the (:number). the number that I'm looking for equals self.id from row just updated. if that makes sense.. thanks.!

Comment: Try it as `self.number`, also if you are looking for it by `id` you could use just `MyModel.find`

Comment: It didn't work for me, is giving me error :undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass, ill try playing around your concept. thanks.

Comment: That error makes me think that it's not pulling the `number` correctly, try printing out `self` before the call to make sure it's what you expect

Comment: I actually found another way of doing what i wanted, though this pointed me in right direction , thanks!